# list assignment index out of range by Python

Tags: python

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
a=[n+1]
for i in range(n+1):
    a[i]=0
a[0]=a[1]=1
for i in range(n+1):
    a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2]
for i in range(n+1):
    sum+=a[i]*a[i]
print((sum+1)%m)
```

---

```
        a[i]=0

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

---

Can you help me ? list assignment index out of range. I can not fix.

Comment: Whatever you think `a=[n+1]` does, it doesn't do that. It creates a list of length 1, containing the value `n+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages like Java require you to create an array of a specific length. Python lets you initialize a list, either empty or populated, and then you can simply append items to the list. If you want to create a list `a` of length `n+1` containing a 0 in each element, you can do that with a list comprehension: `a = [0 for item in range(n+1)]`.

You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable, as `sum` is a Python built-in function. However, if you do choose to override a built-in function, you have to actually assign something to it first. Adding a number to `sum` with `sum+=a[i]*a[i]` attempts to add the square of `a[i]` to a function, which doesn't work.

Keep in mind that a negative-numbered index in a Python list, as with `a[i-2]` when `i` is less than 2, starts from the end of the list: `mylist[-1]` is the last item in a list, `mylist[-2]` is the second to last item, and so on. So the first item in the list, a 1, is set to the sum of the last and second-to-last items, which is 0. The second item, also a 1, is set to the sum of the first item (now a 0) and the last item (still 0), which is also 0. Now your list is all zeros.

I've made a few changes to the parts of your code that produced errors, and added comments so that you can see what each part does, given reasonable inputs like n=3 and m=5:

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
a=[0 for item in range(n+1)] # initialize all to 0
mysum = 0 # initialize a sum that doesn't override the builtin
a[0]=a[1]=1 # set first 2 elements to 1
for i in range(n+1): # for every item in a,
    a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2] # this ends up setting everything to 0
for i in range(n+1): # for every item in a,
    mysum+=a[i]*a[i] # add 0*0 to the sum
print((mysum+1)%m) # 1 modulo anything greater than 1 is 1, so this prints 1
```

So this program doesn't do much more than print `1`.

Comment: j=1
n=int(input())
flag=[]*29
a=[]*29
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=1.0/(i+2)
for j in range(2**29):
    temp=j
    index=0
    sum=0
    while temp>0 and index<29:
        flag[index]=temp%2
        index=index+1
        sum+=(temp%2)*a[index]
        temp=temp/2
if sum==1:
    count=0
    index=index+1
    for i in range(index):
        if flag[i]==1:
            count+=1
    if count==n:
        for i in range(len(flag)):
            if flag[i]!=0:
                print(flag[i]+"/"+(i+2)+"")

Comment: list assignment index out of range

Comment: I can't understand that code block without formatting. Edit it into your original question and it'll be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get input values
n = 10
m = 100

# Initialize list
fib = [1,1]
# Fibonacci sequence of length n
for i in range(2,n): # Adjust the number of iterations to your problem
    fib.append(fib[-1]+fib[-2])

# List comprehension for creating the "squares" list and getting its sum
result = sum([fib[i]**2 for i in range(len(fib))]) % m

print fib
print result
```